# Angular 2 execute observable with interval

Tags: angular

Assuming I have the following code:

```
let sub = Observable.interval(1000).map((x) => {
           let date1= Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000);
            this.diff = date2 - date1;
    }).subscribe((x) => { 
    });
```

The observable works great and executed every second, but my problem is that it's watiting one second even when it's the first execute.

I need to execute the observable, then appeal the 1 sec interval. How I can do that with angular 2?

Comment: where `date2 ` has defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work (not sure):

```
let sub = Observable.interval(1000).startWith(0).map((x) => {
    let date1= Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000);
        this.diff = date2 - date1;
    }).subscribe((x) => { 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, and it's `startWith`